# Moved library and compiler - the resulting .a file is 10 x bigger. How to find the root cause?

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, gcc4.7

One of the projects that I work on depends on another,  very large in-house library.

The CMake file for my project is generated based on the library CMake file - which specifies compiler, compiler switches and so on. The old library had specified the compiler as gcc 4.3.2, while the new one as gcc 4.7.0

When we moved to the new library version, the binaries produced for my project grew something like 10 times bigger - from 35MB to 123MB

Executing nm on the .a file, showed me that the same .o files produced the .a file for both versions of the library.

However, there seem to be ~30% more symbols (as counted by wc -l) in .a file produced with the new library version.

What could be potential reasons for this blowup in binary size? I realise there could be many, however I'm completely clueless - any hints would help.

Comment: 32 bit to 64 bit? Compiling with debug symbols? And incidentally, you do mean `nm libsomething.a | wc -l` don't you? Not just `wc -l libsomething.a`.

Comment: 32bit vs 64bit - no - it is compiled on the same OS  - and shouldn't result in a 10x blowup anyway.

Yes, it is nm libsomething.a | wc -l

How would you check for debug symbols?

Comment: Ah it is nm -a. No this doesn't seem to lead to a significant change...